# Selenium global CacheLookup with WebElement exclusions

Tags: selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, pageobjects, page-factory

I understand the basics of the Selenium [CacheLookup] tag, and that it can be applied to Web Elements to allow them to resolve more quickly on subsequent requests.  Since most elements are candidates for this, **I am seeking a way to apply a single "Global" [CacheLookup] to all Web Elements within a Page Object at once**, and then for the rare elements that are too dynamic for this, have something like an **[ExcludeFromCacheLookup] tag** applied to those few elements, on an element by element basis.  Does anyone know if this is possible?  Better yet, is it possible to apply this format to an entire "Page Object" assembly (.Net project in my case)?

I've scoured the internet, but haven't found anything that states if it is or is not possible.  This would be very useful in general, but being that I am retroactively applying this tag to existing elements, for which there are hundreds of them scattered among dozens upon dozens of Page Objects, it will be a huge time saver.

Thank you for any tips!

Comment: I am fairly certain that it currently cannot be done, but I think it is a good suggestion to present as a suggested feature to the page factory git page (whatever it is).

Comment: You can, not too easy though: you need to define your own annotation, say `ExcludeFromCacheLookup`, then (assuming you are using .net here) extend `DefaultPageObjectMemberDecorator.cs` to recognize that annotation, and then make sure `InitElements` of PageFactory is called with your custom decorator, using signature `InitElements(object page, IElementLocator locator, IPageObjectMemberDecorator decorator)`

Comment: A bit more time effort than I'm willing to put in, and still does not resolve the [CacheLookup] annotation being applied once at the Page Object level for all Web Elements.  Was hoping there was a more straightforward approach built in to Selenium that I somehow was not finding, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  I basically just ended up applying a "Find->Replace" solution as follows:  Find "[FindsBy", Replace with "[CacheLookup][FindsBy".  Thanks nonetheless, Bill and Kiril, for the feedback!

Comment: I refined my previous solution even more, as follows:  1.  In Find->Replace window (Ctrl-F), Select/Check the "Use Regular Expressions" option.  2. In the "Find" box, enter "\\[FindsBy".  3.  In the "Replace" box, enter "[CacheLookup]\n\t\t[FindsBy".

Comment: What language are you using? I guess it doesn't differ to much in this case anyway. If you leave elements that are dynamic without the [CacheLookup](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/cachelookup-in-pageobjectmodel/) attribute is that not clear enough?

Comment: Hi Lloyd.  I was looking to auto-set, all at once, at the Page Object level, all web elements within a Page Object to have the [CacheLookup] annotation.  Then, after auto-setting at the Page Object level dozens of web elements to have the [CacheLookup] annotation, I can go back and manually override the 1 or 2 web elements on the page that are dynamic (if any at all) to have an "[ExcludeFromCacheLookup]" annotation.